# Null point always

Tags: java, session, servlet-filters

It all ways passing null point after this line, `System.out.println("Inside the filter.............."  )`; so can anyone tell me what's wrong in my code and logic

and home.jsp(index page) did not display. here I want to filter every url and proceed only valid login users requests. here my logic..

UserServlet.java

```
 private void loginDetail(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException{

            User u = new User();
            UserService us =new UserServiceImpl() ;

            String Uname = request.getParameter("txtUname");        
            String Pwrd = request.getParameter("txtPwrd");  

            u.setUname(Uname);
            u.setPwrd(Pwrd);

            System.out.println(Uname+""+Pwrd);
            try {
                if(us.Userlogin(u.getUname(),u.getPwrd())){
                    String message = "Thank you, " + Uname +"..You are now logged into the system";             
                    request.setAttribute("message", message);
                    //RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/menu.jsp");
                    //rd.forward(request, response); 
                    HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
                    session.setAttribute("loggedUser", u);
                    String reqUrl = (String)session.getAttribute("requestedURL");
                    session.removeAttribute("requestedURL");
                    response.sendRedirect(reqUrl);              
                }else{
// direct to login}
```

FilterRequest.java

```
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        this.filterConfig = filterConfig;
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
      HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
      HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) resp;
      System.out.println("Inside the filter.............."  );
      HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
      User u = null;
      if(session.getAttribute("loggedUser")!=null){
          u = (User) session.getAttribute("loggedUser");
      }       
      if (u!= null)
      {
          System.out.println("user does exits.." + u.getUname() );
          chain.doFilter(req, resp);          
      }else{
          String message = "Please Login!";             
          req.setAttribute("loginMsg", message);
          //response.sendRedirect("login2.jsp");
      }
    }
```

web.xml

```
  <filter>
        <filter-name>FilterRequest</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.mobitel.bankdemo.web.FilterRequest</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>FilterRequest</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

stack trace

```
 `Jul 11, 2013 10:24:26 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin;.;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre6/bin/client;C:/Program Files/Java/jre6/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre6/lib/i386;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Kaspersky Lab\Kaspersky Anti-Virus 6.0 for Windows Workstations MP4\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_07/bin;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.2\bin;D:\common libs\com.mysql.jdbc_5.1.5.jar;;C:\Users\lcladmin\Documents\Softwares\java related\eclipse-jee-indigo-win32_2\eclipse;
Jul 11, 2013 10:24:26 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:BankDemoWeb' did not find a matching property.
Jul 11, 2013 10:24:27 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jul 11, 2013 10:24:27 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jul 11, 2013 10:24:27 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 554 ms
Jul 11, 2013 10:24:27 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jul 11, 2013 10:24:27 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.41
Jul 11, 2013 10:24:27 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jul 11, 2013 10:24:27 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jul 11, 2013 10:24:27 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 517 ms
Inside the filter..............
user does exits..`
```

Thank you..

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow... it would be really helpful if you had a somewhat more informative and concise title than "what's wrong with my code" for your questions. [Here's one FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: Null check your `req` parameter.  Include the stack trace.

Comment: @eebbesen have you done Java web development before? Surely that's not the problem.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I'm open to alternatives, but using the groovyConsole (yes, not straight Java): `groovy> d = null 
groovy> d2 = (Object) d 
groovy> System.out.println(d2) null` it seems possible that a null reference can be cast.  I'll await the stack trace but admit that I could be off base.

Comment: @eebbesen well, the req and resp objects are directly injected from the application server when a request is done to the server and pass through this filter. So none of these objects will be `null`.

Comment: Hey im a beginner for java. so please can anyone explain with a code ? thank you..

Comment: could you please post the stack trace?

Comment: If you post the stacktrace, you will get real help. As the code looks, it should work as expected.

Comment: See my updated question friends..please help me to do this. Thank you for that friends :)

Comment: From your stacktrace, the problem looks to be in your servlet (or the class controller you're using) and not in your filter.

Comment: login thing worked perfectly before filter comes. so can anyone tell me what is the error in servlet?

Comment: here i wanted to do display index page and then filter other all request before proceed. how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You have a real simple problem: The user is not logged in ;)

To clarify things:

In you `Filter` you're checking if the user is logged in and in this case execute the chain with

```
chain.doFilter(req, resp);
```

That's fine so far.

*But what happens if the user is not logged in?* In this case you're not executing the chain and therefore no `Servlet`. The `Servlet` is always the last element in the chain.

So your users cannot log in as they never get to the `Servlet` that allows them to log in as you filter them out before.

You have to extend your filter to allow logins when no user is logged in. This can be done e.g. by changing the `url-pattern` of the `Filter`.

Comment: yeh..i did it Uwe Plonus, using what u said.. now it is working. thank you all of you :)

Comment: @user1758876 If an answer has helped you it is nice to accept the answer and perhaps upvote it.